# Tax on services rendered prior year/ payment received current year

Tags: income-tax

If I get paid for services (net 30) rendered in the prior year (22) in current year (23) is the amount taxable in TY22?

Comment: It would be best to mention the jurisdiction when you're asking about taxes. I can answer that for Saudi Arabia - it wouldn't matter as there's no income tax for individuals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about U.S. taxes, that depends on your selection of Accounting Method on line F of [Schedule C for Profit or Loss from Business](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040sc) (if that's the one you use, or on similar line of other form).

The accounting method for 2022 will be the same one you stated on your Schedule C for your 2021 tax return, if you were engaged in the same business back then.

Otherwise if you did want to change your accounting method, you would need to file [Form 3115](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-3115).

If you select Cash basis, the payment is included in your 2023 income.

If you select Accrual basis, the payment is included in your 2022 income.